# Where to find a list of special character representations?

Tags: vim

For example backspace is `<BS>` and tab is `<Tab>`, but where can I look them up if I don't know or remember the sequence for, say, the up or down arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two `:help`ful tricks:

- In insert mode and in the command line, hitting `<C-v>` followed by some key inserts that key's internal notation.

  For example,

  `:help`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>

  produces

  `:help <Up>`
- The `:help` command supports completion so you can type a keyword related to what you want and hit `<Tab>` or `<C-d>`:

  `:help key<Tab>`

Answer (score 3):

I was going to ask this, but then I found the answer by random luck in the help files. So here it is for those who are looking for the same:

`:help keycodes`